# C# Delegates (Output not showing correct values)

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to get the output of  "1111111111".
The Message function is called by AddMessage and it stores the message into an array. 
However when i output the array values, I get the address instead of the value. How do i fix this?

```
class Program
{
    public delegate int print();

    public static void Main()
    {
        print[] array1 = new print[10];

        AddMessage(ref array1, Message);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
        }
    }


    public static void AddMessage(ref print[] array, print msg)
    {
        for(int i =0; i< 10; i++)
        {
            array[i] = msg;
        }
    }

    public static int Message()
    {
        int msg;
        msg = 1;
        return msg;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: In your code there is no need for `ref` in `ref print[] array` - just `print[] array` will do. Why have you put `ref`?

Answer (score 2):

A delegate is a function, you're passing a reference to the function itself (not the result) into `Console.WriteLine`.

```
Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
```

must turn into

```
Console.WriteLine(array1[i]());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the object name because you're not calling the delegate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
}
```

You should change this to `array1[i]()`

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.